# How to solve in ReasonReact - "This has type: (ReasonReact.reactElement, string) => unit But somewhere wanted: at <anonymous>actElement

Tags: reason, reason-react

I have a very compact ReasonReact reducer component, which has a component, initialState, reducer, action, and render function as follows:

```
type actions =
  | DoNothing;

let component = ReasonReact.reducerComponent("ShowHide");

let make = (~name, _children) => {
  ...component,
  initialState: () => 0, /* here, state is an `int` */
  reducer: (action, state) =>
    switch action {
      | DoNothing => ReasonReact.NoUpdate;
    },
  render: (self) => {
    let greeting =
      "Hello: " ++ name ++ ". You've clicked the button " ++ string_of_int(self.state) ++ " time(s)!";
    <div></div>
  }
};
```

I am trying to render in my app.re file using the `ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId` function:

```
<div id = "RenderShowHide"></div>
        ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(<ShowHide name="hello" />, "RenderShowHide")
```

However, the Reason/Bucklescript compiler is complaining as follows:

```
This has type:
    (ReasonReact.reactElement, string) => unit
  But somewhere wanted:
    at <anonymous>actElement
```

However, I am having a difficulty what an actElement is. Any suggestions as to what an actElement is, and how I can go around fixing the above, would be more than appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That looks like something is swallowing part of the compiler error message. Can you run the compile with the plain `bsb` command and post the output?

Comment: I am receiving the same error message with the bsb command.

Comment: I've also re-install bsb to latest, rm -rf'd node_modules and package-lock.json. In addition, to updating to latest version of reason. Still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the repo you posted: https://github.com/CharlieGreenman/reason-react-razroo

```
npm install
bsb -make-world
```

I got the following error message:

```
  We've found a bug for you!
  /Users/yawar/src/reason-react-razroo/src/app.re 16:9-40

  14 ┆ </div>
  15 ┆ <p className="App-intro">
  16 ┆   ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(<ShowHide name="hello"/>, "index")
  17 ┆   (ReasonReact.stringToElement("To get started, edit"))
  18 ┆   <code> (ReasonReact.stringToElement(" src/app.re ")) </code>

  This has type:
    (ReasonReact.reactElement, string) => unit
  But somewhere wanted:
    ReasonReact.reactElement
```

It looks like something in your build tooling was swallowing part of your error message. The main problem is on l. 16; if you get rid of that line the error will go away. If you want to render the `ShowHide` component, then change the line to just the literal JSX, not the call to `ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId`.

I have two more general recommendations; try to stick with the bsb-provided React skeleton project unless you are expert-level, because it's way simpler and much better supported:

```
bsb -init my-project -theme react
```

And, try to post the entire error message for future errors, starting from the 'We've found a bug for you!' line. That will help diagnose a lot.

Comment: I am trying to create an enterprise level reason react app, and from I understand reason react scripts is better in that regard.

Comment: @Master-Chief OK, no worries. I'll ask in the Discord about strategies for taking the bsb template to enterprise level; I know people have definitely done it in their own projects.